# Text patterns from classification

Tags: classification, pattern-recognition, text-classification, naivebayes

Say I have some kind of multi-class text/conversation classificator (naive bayes or so) and I wanted to find text patterns that were significant for the classification. How would I best go about finding these text patterns? The motivation behind this is you could use these patterns to better understand the process behind the classification.

A pattern is defined as a (multi)set of words `s={w1, ... , wn}`, this pattern has a class probability for each class c - `P(c|s)` - inferred by the classificator. A pattern is then significant, if the inferred probability is high (local maximum, top n, something like that).

Now it wouldn't be such a problem to run the classificator on parts of text in the dataset you are looking at. However, these patterns do not have to be natural sentences or something like that, but any (multi)subset of the vocabulary. You are then looking at running the classification on all the (multi)subsets of the vocabulary, which is computationally unrealistic.

I think what could work is to search the text space using a heuristic search algorithm such as hill climbing to maximize the likelyhood of a certain class. You could run the hillclimber a bunch of times from different initial conditions and then just take the top 10 or so unique results as patterns.

Is this a good approach, or are there better ones? Thanks for any suggestions.